# facebook like and share count shows same number

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having fb-like and fb-share button on my page, but when i click like or share button, the count in like and share increases simultaneously.

As for example **like count = 4 and share count = 3**
after liking my web page **Like count =5 and share count = 5**

This is the problem

[image]

**fb-like button code**

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%=ShareURL.ToString() %>&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=100&action=like&font=lucida+grande&colorscheme=light&height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 85px;height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true">
```

**fb-share button code**

```
 <div style="display: inline; float: right; margin-removed 80px;">
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php" name="fb_share">
      share_url="<%=ShareURL.ToString() %>" type="button_count">Share</a>
   <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share">
          type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Facebook Like's and Share's counter must show the same number. See the official description:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#faqlikecount

> **What makes up the number shown next to my Share button?**
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of your URL
> - The number of shares of your URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about your URL

The same rule can be found at Like buttons FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#faq

Answer (score 0):

Make be you have used same Application Variable for like and share count. so when you increase share count, your like count goes on increasing.

use different variable for each.

Comment: I have used just the plugin which is provided by Facebook